# "GlassFish requires Java SE version 6. Your JDK is version 0"

Tags: java, macos, glassfish, macos-catalina

I'm trying to use Glassfish on a Mac running 10.15.6 Catalina. When I run the command,

```
./asadmin start-domain
```

I get the message,

```
"GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0"
```

Numerous posts online said to add to the file "asenv.conf," a path to the JDK, such as

```
AS_JAVA="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Unfortunately, after adding that line (or paths to several other Java location) I'm still getting the error. I know it's reading the file, because when I've made a typo on that line is says there is no version of Java at the location.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are running the right version of Java i.e. Java 8. GlassFish 4 and 5 cannot run on JDK 9 or later.

Comment: Gottcha. I was using Java 14. Thanks!